# In magento How to show differerent image while choosing color attribute of a product

Tags: magento

In my product page i have a created color attribute dropdown and by selecting an option i need to show different color image of that particular product.How to do this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend you [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher). I admit that I'm involved in the development of the extension and I hope this answer it not considered as spam because the extension is free and seams to fit your needs.
The extension does even more than changing some images. It allows you to change the full media block (all images), it allows you to change the default dropdowns of the configurable products to labels or even images of the simple products, it allows you to show the out of stock combinations of the configurable products and you can even set a default combination to be shown when the product page loads.
Full documentation on how to install, features, how to use, how to uninstall and limitations can be found [here](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thank You i ll try to implement it and let you know my result.@Marius

Comment: Hi can you please post anyone demo link which is using this extension?@Marius

Comment: @RamaPriya You can check this: http://www.theladysaysno.be/kledij/jurken/bloomsbury-dress-fever.html. This page uses the extension I mentioned but it's slightly different (older). But the result and logic are the same. Sorry, the website is in Dutch but I think you can manage.

Comment: Fine.i hope it is suitable for my requirement.is it possible only through configurable product or else i can implement this extension for simple product too?@Marius

Comment: @RamaPriya The extension works for configurable products. I also hope it fits your needs. If it doesn't...well..you have the uninstall instructions in there also.

Comment: As i am a beginner in using magento i have not created any configurable products yet.can you please provide some easy tutorial to create configurable products. @Marius

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44884/discussion-between-rama-priya-and-marius)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if there is a magento plugin, allowing you to do this?

If there isn't you would need to do the following:
- add a color field to each image and fill it (or name your images in a way, that you know which color it belongs to)
- add a javascript event to the color dropdown
- when this event fires, get the choosen color, find the first image and select it

Comment: Only paid extensions are available.I have tried by using the jquery from this link http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/create-a-color-switcher-in-magento/ but it is not supporting.Kindly give some suggestion to implement this concept @Seb

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change main image on product detail page or want to show additional image for selected color?

You can do it using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following ways:

- Add custom options to select color. Update image using JQuery or java-script on changing custom option. (Admin can see in order detail, that which option user has selected)
- Add Attributes for color, and make it as Configurable product. And create child products for each color.

Comment: can you please post the javascript @Ankita

Answer (score 0):

Please use configurable product,for that case.After that using Javascript you can image,Because  each configurable product have different simple product .

Comment: can you please post the jquery@Amit Bera